# translating controls in JFace

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have an application that uses org.eclipse.jface.preference.FieldEditorPreferencePage in order to create preference pages. During the time I started internationalizing my app I noticed that I cannot override the creation of buttons named "Restore Defaults" and "Apply", hence names remain English all time.

I have noticed there is a messages.properties file in JFace jar, whose lables are used to assign names. But how to reassign JFace to another bundle then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those string are retrieve from [bundle](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) `"org.eclipse.jface.messages"` their keys are "defaults", "apply".

String  [] labels = JFaceResources.getStrings(new String  [] {"defaults", "apply" });

You should provide the correct resource bundle for your locale, and it should work other thing what you can do is to do not create those buttons by calling protected method  `noDefaultAndApplyButton()`

Answer (score 4):

You need to download a language pack from here:

http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/L-3.2.1_Language_Packs-200609210945/index.php

`NLpack2-eclipse-SDK-3.2.1-gtk.zip` works for me while I'm using Eclipse 3.7.2.

Extract `org.eclipse.jface.nl2_3.2.1.v200609270227.jar` (or other nl for your language) from the archive and add it to your project. It will be used automatically.